# How to convert set of images to proper RSS description?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to build a RSS feed, so first I get the page with `XPath Fetch Page` (XPath is `//div[@class='topic']/h2/a`), then I `Loop` for each item and `XPath Fetch Page` again with `URL` equal to `item.href` and extract images there with `XPath` equal to `//*[@id="topic"]/div[4]/div/div/a/img`. 
In result I get a description, which contains set of images like:

```
0
  alt Sample title
  height 925
  src http://cdn.example.com/f2dd/3702212_6cddf28e.jpg
  style width:640px; height:925px;
  width 640
1
  alt Sample title
  height 920
  src http://cdn.example.com/1cc7/3702213_00acefab.jpg
  style width:640px; height:920px; 
  width 640
...
```

How should I convert it to one text string with a number of `<img src="...">` elements? If I `Loop` thru each item (what is shown on the image below), then I get just one (first) element.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to join / concatenate a list of images... I don't think there's an operator for that.

The next best thing is a dirty hack like this:

1. In your loops, assign to `x` instead of `description`
2. Add a **Regex** operator with params:

   - **in:** `item.description`
   - **replace:** `.*`
   - **with:** `${x.0}${x.1}${x.2}${x.3}${x.4}` (and so on)

**UPDATE**

As [@LA_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604388/la) commented, the replacement should be like this instead: `<img src="${x.0.src}"><br><img src="${x.1.src}">`

Comment: Thanks! The problem here is that `x` is not just URL. So in result I get something like `Some title332http://cdn.example.com/4353/3702856_8c20a82c.pngwidth:632px; height:332px;632Some title929http://cdn.example.com/d559/3702737_2689f9e5.jpgwidth:640px; height:929px;640`.

Comment: How about if you change the replacement to `${x.0.src}${x.1.src}`

Comment: Yes, it works (actually, the replacement should be like `<img src="${x.0.src}"><br><img src="${x.1.src}">`)! Many thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated my post for future pipers ;-)